# Clipping out a CALayer's background color or border?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

In CALayer, you can assign a background color for the fill or the border width and color for the border.

Is there a way to apply a clipping path or mask to have the CALayer not draw a portion of the border or the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `mask` property of your layer to a `CAShapeLayer`, and set the `path` property of the shape layer to your clipping path.  Or you can set the `mask` property of your layer to a regular `CALayer` and set the mask 
layer's `contents` property to a CGImage containing your mask.